# Can I use collectionViewCell 2 Cell in 1 UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Is it possible to use collectionViewCell 2 cells in the same UICollectionView? while cell no. 1 scroll in the horizontal pane, cell no. 2

scroll in the vertical pane and when user scroll cell no. 2, cell no. 1 is moving in the same direction. I did tried to use containerview but

cell no.1 did not go along with cell no. 2. How can I make it work as in the picture?

[image](http://www.mx7.com/i/523/vReQOw.jpg)

Comment: There are only two cells in total?

Comment: You'll need two different collection views (or just table views would work also). You can override `scrollViewDidScroll` to synchronize their movement.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't have cells scrolling in different directions within one `UICollectionView`.

One way to achieve this is to have 2 `UICollectionView`s, make the one on top scroll horizontally and the bottom one vertically.